# why r shows double instead of Vector?

Tags: r

In R, I understand that there are lists and vectors

```
ll <- list(1,2,3)
typeof(ll)
lst <- c(1,2,8)
typeof(lst)
```

result
'list'
'double'

why does `typeof(lst)` gives double instead of vector?

Comment: It is a numeric vector.  You can check `class(lst)` and `is.vector(lst)` `is.atomic`

Comment: All doubles are vectors in R, although for some the length may be 1. `help('typeof')` shows the list of possible types, and "vector" is not a type (double and list are two possible types for vectors)

Comment: Also, even lists (without attributes) are vectors, just not atomic. `x <- list(1)`, `is.vector(x)` gives `TRUE`, `is.atomic(x)` gives `FALSE`.

Comment: I don' think `typeof` will ever return "vector". Vectors in R only hold a single data type so typeof will return the name of that type. Also, `typeof` is really just about storage. If you want to know what an object "is", then `class()` is usually more helpful for that.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand bit more. There is an hierarchy between list and vector and list is a type of vector. Is this correct?